# HotChocolate with Authorize attribute, how to get currently logged on user?

Tags: .net-core, graphql, hotchocolate

I've got a GraphQL mutation using HotChocolate with the `[Authorize]` attribute from `HotChocolate.AspNetCore.Authorization` to enforce authorization on my GraphQL endpoints.

This works fine, I can only call the mutation once I'm logged in as an Admin ...

... but now I'd like to retrieve the user which is authorized, but I don't seem to find a way to do it.

```
[ExtendObjectType(Name = "Mutation")]
[Authorize(Roles = new[] { "Administrators" })]
public class MyMutations
{
    public bool SomeMethod()
    {
        // In a regular Web API controller, you can do User.Identity.Name to fetch the user name of the current user.  What is the equivalent in Hot Chocolate?
        var userName = "";


        return false;
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HotChocolate uses the asp.net core authentication mechanisms, so you can get the user using the HttpContext.

```cs
[ExtendObjectType(Name = "Mutation")]
[Authorize(Roles = new[] { "Administrators" })]
public class MyMutations
{
    public bool SomeMethod([Service] IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor)
    {
        var user = contextAccessor.HttpContext.User; // <-> There is your user

        // In a regular Web API controller, you can do User.Identity.Name to fetch the user name of the current user.  What is the equivalent in Hot Chocolate?
        var userName = "";


        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well I'll be damned.  I thought that *could* be the case, but I actually just did not try it.  Silly me :)  Thanks!